# iOS features and buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an application which was rejected. The rejection says it contains lower quality experience, and I should add iOS features to it, like a favourite button.

It's a language learner application, which is just a "webview", so it does not contains much, but textviews and a few pictures. Though it has a nice design and a lot of animation, but still don't have that interactive thing or button.

Could anyone help me by showing me the way how to improve my app to be accepted?
How can I make those iOS features?
What buttons should I make and how?

I know there is a lot of way to do these, but I'm asking because I'm not a programmer and I believe you can explain it to me, or link me the right pages to learn and achieve my goal.

Appreciate any help.

On Android it was fine to just make that "lame" application which has nothing but textviews with pictures.

I also don't want my users to have internet connection while using the app.

Basically, I just need buttons which can do something.

Comment: So you asking "programmers" about design? I think you should ask designers first.

Comment: If your app is nothing but a web view then why did you create an app? Just point users to the website.

Comment: No, i'm asking for interactive things, like a favourite button. Actually they said that I need something interactive, because all my users can do is read the grammar.

Comment: It could be bookmark too. I also will create a nightmode to my app. Things like that

Comment: I don't want to just give them a point to the website, because they should have to use internet connection, and later I also want to make a quiz in the app

Comment: Shouldn't they have internet connection for the WebView ?

Comment: The main thing is that right now they don't need the acces to the internet, and I want my application to be accepted. Apple said that they just need something interactive.. Buttons which can do something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you didn't read the [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

The *second* point in the introduction reads…

> - If your app looks like it was cobbled together in a few days, or
>     you're trying to get your first practice app into the store to impress
>     your friends, please brace yourself for rejection. We have lots of
>     serious developers who don't want their quality apps to be surrounded
>     by amateur hour.

Please don't waste the reviewers' time with a "language learner application" - write and submit something of value

Comment: I don't think my language learner app  doesn't have value. It has 20k downloader on android with a 4,9 rating out of 5. And they love it, thats why they are asking for ios version. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's Android for you - there is a lower barrier to entry. On iOS you can't put a *"lame application which has nothing but textviews with pictures."* in the store.

Comment: That's why i'm asking for help. How to impress apple?

Comment: Should I just add bookmark and nightmode?

Comment: I was just trying to make a good mood for him, so maybe he could help me with my case :), but soon i will realize that i will have to choose the time-waster tactic, which means learning and a lot of reading on the internet. I was just trying to save time for myself.

Comment: @CsJohn You call "learning" a waste of time? What? You are clearly not doing this because you like it. I have no idea why you would try to write an app when you have no skill and clearly no interest to develop it either. This question is completely off topic to StackOverflow anyway so I'm just gonna put in my vote to close the question.